# .bashrc modifications not taking effect

Tags: bash, arch-linux, path

A very basic question that I can't figure out the answer to: in my `$HOME/.bashrc` I'm setting up all sorts of stuff including the `PATH` environment variable, e.g. via:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

I have now noticed - and I'm not sure if this is only the case after a system upgrade (I'm on Arch) - that after commenting out every line in my `.bashrc` when I open another terminal emulator instance (e.g. xterm) `PATH` is still set up as if I had not modified my `.bashrc` at all. That seems very strange to me as it is definitely the only file on my system containing this particular `PATH` setup code. What's happening here?

Comment: Check the other dotfiles, like `.profile` aswell

Comment: Are you running bash, or zsh? Can you post the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: @Panki: I've checked `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Weirdly enough aliases etc. from my `.bashrc` don' take effect in new bash instances, just the path seems to be cached somehow.

Comment: @GMaster: I'm using bash 5.1.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell is if this is a local machine or if you logging in through `ssh`. Once logged in, what is the output of `echo $-`? And show us the output of `grep -H PATH ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`.